# parsing <br> tag in scrapy

Tags: loops, parsing, scrapy

I'm trying to parse data from a store locator website, which has 
 tags between address and contact information.

On the website, the source code looks like this:

```
<a href="https://my.xx.com/storefinder/555" class="store-box"><h3>Aberdeen - King St</h3><p>215 King St,<br>AB24 5DA<br>Phone: 123456</p></a>
```

My scrapy code looks like this:

```
import scrapy

from xx.items import xxItem

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'xx_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.my.xx.com']
    start_urls = [
                'https://my.xx.com/storefinder/list/a  
]

    def parse(self, response):  
        rows = response.css('div.col-md-4.col-sm-6')
        for row in rows:
            item = xxItem()  
            item['name'] = row.css('h3::text').extract()
            item['address'] = row.css('p::text').extract() 

            yield item
```

My output is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L43nC.png)

How do I parse the address, postcode etc into separate columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you use `::text` selector on than `a` tag element - it will save each text element between tags as separate element:

```
def parse(self, response):  
    for row in response.css('div.col-md-4.col-sm-6'):
        item = xxItem()  
        item['name'] = row.css('h3::text').extract()
        item['address'] = row.css('p::text').extract() 

        a_tag = row.css("a") # assuming that `a` tag inside row

        item["url"] = a_tag.css("*::attr(href)").extract_first()
        # python list unpacking:
        item["city"], item["address_"], item["post_code"], item["phone"] = a_tag.css("*::text").extract()
        if " " in item["phone"]:
            item["phone"] = item["phone"].split(" ")[-1] # get only phone number without 'Phone: '

       yield item
```